# Vertical rule in tables with multicol span

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am trying to create a table to compare to set of methods for various parameters.

My tex:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l|ccc|ccc}
  \hline
  Sequence & \multicolumn{3}{c}{D-GEM} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{DVO}\\
  %\cline{2-4} \cline{4-7}
  & $\delta=1$  & $\delta=10$ & $\delta=30$ & $\delta=1$ & $\delta=10$ & $\delta=30$ \\
  \hline
 Gnat & 13.65      & 13.65       & 13.65     & 13.65        & 13.65    & 13.65    \\
Gnat &         & each        & 0.01      & 13.65        & gram     & 13.65    \\
Gnat &  13.65       & 13.65     & 92.50      & 13.65      & 13.65    & 13.65    \\
Gnat &  13.65       & 13.65     & 33.33      & 13.65      & 13.65    & 13.65   \\
Gnat &  13.65 & 13.65      & 8.99   & 13.65      & 13.65    & 13.65    \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{Put caption here}
\label{tab:RPE_X1}
\end{table}
```

My output looks like
[image]

My question is how to get the vertical rule in the top most header row, ie. between D-GEM and DVO.

Comment: Have a look at the `booktabs` package. You'll probably Need to add  `\cmidrule{2-7}` after the `\\ ` of that line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\multicolumn` for D-GEM misses the `|`:

```
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{D-GEM}
```

> [image: Result]

And a version without vertical lines with package `booktabs`. Package `siunitx` helps for the alignment of the numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l*{6}{S[table-format=2.2]}}
  \toprule
  Sequence & \multicolumn{3}{c}{D-GEM} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{DVO}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
  & {$\delta=1$} & {$\delta=10$} & {$\delta=30$}
  & {$\delta=1$} & {$\delta=10$} & {$\delta=30$} \\
  \midrule
  Gnat & 13.65 & 13.65  & 13.65 & 13.65 & 13.65  & 13.65 \\
  Gnat &       & {each} &  0.01 & 13.65 & {gram} & 13.65 \\
  Gnat & 13.65 & 13.65  & 92.50 & 13.65 & 13.65  & 13.65 \\
  Gnat & 13.65 & 13.65  & 33.33 & 13.65 & 13.65  & 13.65 \\
  Gnat & 13.65 & 13.65  &  8.99 & 13.65 & 13.65  & 13.65 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Put caption here}
\label{tab:RPE_X1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with booktabs and siunitx]

Comment: perfect...bull's eye answer!

Answer (score 3):

Horizontal or vertical line?
If horizontal then see below, else see above Heiko's answer.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l|ccc|ccc}
  \hline
  Sequence & \multicolumn{3}{c}{D-GEM} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{DVO} \\ \cline{2-7}
  & $\delta=1$  & $\delta=10$ & $\delta=30$ & $\delta=1$ & $\delta=10$ & $\delta=30$ \\
  \hline
Gnat & 13.65 & 13.65 & 13.65 & 13.65 & 13.65 & 13.65 \\
Gnat &       & each  & 0.01  & 13.65 & gram  & 13.65 \\
Gnat & 13.65 & 13.65 & 92.50 & 13.65 & 13.65 & 13.65 \\
Gnat & 13.65 & 13.65 & 33.33 & 13.65 & 13.65 & 13.65 \\
Gnat & 13.65 & 13.65 & 8.99  & 13.65 & 13.65 & 13.65 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{Put caption here}
\label{tab:RPE_X1}
\end{table}
```

Just put the `\cline` at the end of your row.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, your answer relates to the original version of the question which has now been edited to ask for vertical rules.