# Vertical line not shown in a booktabs style table.

Tags: tables, booktabs

I have a table with four columns with some added annotations. 
I use `booktabs` style with vertical lines to separate the two large categories (hardware and software) in the table. 
The issue is that the vertical line is not shown in the first column.

What might be wrong? Additionally, I don't think it's a good idea to have a vertical line in the table, but without the vertical line, it is hard to read the contents; what options do I have to remove the vertical line, but distinctively separate the columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\spaceit}{\hspace{0.2cm}}

\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[t]
        \caption{Research history \& directions}
        \centering

        \begin{threeparttable}

        \begin{tabular}{@{}l|ll|ll@{}} \toprule
         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Software} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Hardware}\\ 
         \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(r){4-5}
                     & Data structures \& Algorithms & Software Engineering & Hardware Systems & Communication\\ \midrule
         A & \tnote{1}\spaceit Ray tracing modeling   & Widget framework                 &                                       & VLC\tnote{a} \\ 
         \bottomrule
         \end{tabular}

         \begin{tablenotes}
             \item[1] Published academic research: papers, books, technical reports ({1} -- {10})
             \item[a] Visible Light Communication
             \item[b] Component Based Software Engineering
             \item[c] Data Acquisition System
             \item[d] Web-based System Management
             \item[e] Software \& Hardware Testing System
         \end{tablenotes}

         \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}         
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have set no vertical rule on the left. It is a bad idea to use vertical rule with `booktabs` commands.

Comment: The problem is unrelated to `booktabs`; you need `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Software}`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267024/21344 for full solution and also a way to typeset a similar table, separating the groups without resorting to vertical rules.

Comment: The `booktabs` perspective is that it is a bad idea to use vertical rules with tables. Loading `booktabs` will not make the use of vertical rules any better or any worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to separate the two groups in a nicer way:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,  svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\newcommand{\spaceit}{\hspace{0.2cm}}

\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
  \caption{Research history \& directions}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lll cll@{}}
      \arrayrulecolor{black} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-3} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{5-6}
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Software} &\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\color{Lavender}\rule[-9.4ex]{1.5em}{12ex}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Hardware}\\
      \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(r){5-6}
        & Data structures \& Algorithms & Software Engineering &   & Hardware Systems & Communication \\
      \addlinespace
      A & \tnote{1}\spaceit Ray tracing modeling & Widget framework & & VLC\tnote{a} \\
      \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-3} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{5-6}
    \end{tabular}
    \smallskip
    \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
      \item[1] Published academic research: papers, books, technical reports ({1} -- {10})
      \item[a] Visible Light Communication
      \item[b] Component Based Software Engineering
      \item[c] Data Acquisition System
      \item[d] Web-based System Management
      \item[e] Software \& Hardware Testing System
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]